# create command line in Symfony 2 : add private fields

Tags: symfony, command-line

I read the documentation concerning the creation of command lines in Symfony 2.
I wanted to create a Command class a little bit different. Indeed, I want to add the translator as a private field of my class... just like this :

```
<?php

namespace myVendor\myBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ThemeCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
private $translator;

public function __construct() {
    $this->translator = $this->getContainer()->get('translator');
}

protected function configure() {
    $this->setName('viewkit:color')
         ->setDescription($this->translator->trans('command.theme.description'))
         ->addArgument('theme', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'le thème jquery');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $theme = $input->getArgument('theme');        
    $output->writeln($this->translator->trans('command.theme.success'));
}
```

}

```
?>
```

As you can imagine it does not work because of the constructor and I have this exception :

```
Call to a member function getKernel() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\viewkit\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand.php
```

the problem is the **getContainer** méthod in the abstract class *ContainerAwareCommand* that returns probably null
and as this class comes from *Command.php* class, the problem is more specifically the Command.php **getApplication** method that returns a non-object (null probably)..

Somehow the **application** field of the Command.php class is filled but as I have my contructor in my *ThemeCommand*, there is a problem

So my question is :
How can I have private fields in my ThemeCommand class and init them with a well-done constructor

Thank you

---

I made another test getting rid of the constructor and doing like in the documentation...same problem, the constructor is not the problem but getContainer does not return an object because **getApplication** in Command.php is null

Comment: Haw do you call your command from CLI ?

Comment: I am using netbeans, so the command lines are loaded and the exception appears at this time... if i dont use translator, it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when configure method is called, or when the contructor is called, the application object is null. It is only in the execute method that a service can be called because, in the meantime, the application object is filled

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you elaborate a bit more with this answer?

Comment: It has been a while but I meant that I cannot call the service in the constructor...I have to call it in the methods. So I got rid of my private field and when I need to translate (in execute method for example) I call the service $this->getContainer()->get('translator')->trans()

Answer (score 2):

You forgot calling parent constructor !

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->translator = $this->getContainer()->get('translator');
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but the parent is an abstract class, so there is no constructor

Comment: so I imagined to call the grand-parent constructor : Command::__construct()... but I have another exception evrytime i call trans() method, it is like $translator is not an object (null probably)

Comment: __construct is always callable (but in static context), as it is defined or not. And, in this case, ContainerAwareCommand doesn't redefine it but Command does...

Comment: especially because an abstract class cannot be instanciated